# How to launch QGIS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, package-managers, qgis

I have installed *QGIS* through the package manager and I can run `gpx2shp` via terminal. How to launch *QGIS* though?

In my Ubuntu, I go to the nautilus and I get as result a *QGIS* desktop icon, which, on click, launches the gui of the application. How to do that in *Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)*?

---

Below is the package manager's view:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Install `qgis` package (4th in you second screenshot). By then you should gain a desktop icon. If not, open a terminal and type `qgis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `qgis` package (4th in you second screenshot). By then you should gain a desktop icon. If not, open a terminal and type `qgis`.

Alternatively you can open a terminal and install QGIS from there:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis
```